# Best weapon to destroy enemy aircraft in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I haven't found a lock-on launcher in COD: Ghosts multiplayer.  What is the best weapon for taking out an enemy killstreak aircraft, e.g. helicopter?

Comment: I am thinking the MAW may be a lock-on. This has be retrieved via killstreak or care package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are far fewer aircraft in Ghosts than in previous CoD games, so it no longers makes sense to carry an anti-air weapon.  An LMG with FMJs is the best weapon to use as it tears through aircraft in seconds.  Plus, it's useful against infantry, whereas the MAAWS isn't.

Comment: LMG with FMJ works pretty good.  i set up a loadout like this and have been swatting choppers out of the sky like flies.

Answer (score 0):

LMG's are great for taking out aircraft but the MAAWS can lock on to aircraft if you keep the targeting laser on the aircraft for long enough. Another launcher you can use to take out aircraft is the MK32. It does require some skill though especially against Helo Pilots. It will take down Helo Scouts and Pilots down with only 2 semtexes but for Battle Hinds I don't know. 
(Information is from personal experience)